# Menu bound to collection only shows first element

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dockpanel

I am trying to bind an ObservableCollection to a DockPanel ItemsControl. I would like to be able to control the MenuItems in the DockPanel through data binding. My approach seems to have kinda worked, however, it is only displaying the first element 'DockItems'. Here is my code,

```
    <ItemsControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding DockItems}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Menu>
                    <MenuItem Header="File">
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </MenuItem>
                </Menu>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the behavior I wanted by adding a ContentControl and binding it to a ViewModel with the ObservableCollection as a property. I am not sure why I needed this extra layer to get things working, though I do prefer this approach.

```
    <ContentControl Name="DockItemsContent" Content="{Binding DockItemsViewModel}">
        <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <Menu>
                        <MenuItem Header="File" ItemsSource="{Binding DockItems}">
                            <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Name}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </Menu>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
    </ContentControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear at all what you're trying to do here. You're creating an ItemsControl, so a completely separate menu will be created for each element in your list. Each menu will have a "File" item with one list item under it. Doesn't make sense.

Both Menu and MenuItem have an ItemsSource, I suspect what you're actually trying to do is this:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="File" ItemsSource="{Binding DockItems}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
</Menu>
```